# Imprompto shortcode failure

Tags: wordpress

A while back, I created a WordPress website with over 50+ pages, that had very similar content. I used shortcodes to create a bit of dynamism on the various pages. Everything has been fine for a while until yesterday.

The shortcodes are not working and the "shortcode text" is being displayed raw. Even the shortcode for contact form7 recaptcha doesn't work either. I checked my functions file to see if the shortcodes I defined were there -- I didn't find anything. I tried to rewrite everything again, but even the new ones I am creating aren't working either.

Comment: Was WP updated? A lot of things changed in 5+. Can you roll back to before that?

Comment: did you try to turn on debug in wp-config.php and see if there is some error showing up? i assume your shortcode is in functions.php?